# automatically reboot windows if it was on lock screen

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, lock-screen

I wanted to see if there is anyway on windows 10 that I can do a automatic reboot if device was on lock screen. the reason is our machines randomly stuck on lock screen which they will be fixed with simple reboot. I wanted to see if there is anyway I can automate it.

Comment: You could try to create a task in task scheduler. Then set "on workstation lock" as the trigger and add a script which reboot comptuer as the action.

Comment: you do not have any idea how your solution helped me. Thanks a million. I wish I could like your comment million times.

Answer (score 1):

Update here: 
Joy's answer worked perfect for me. here is his solution:

> You could try to create a task in task scheduler. Then set "on
>   workstation lock" as the trigger and add a script which reboot
>   comptuer as the action

Comment: Joy, is there anyway you can think about rebooting if the machine was on lock screen for more than 10 seconds?